# How to Display only one MainActivity in Android Device from Project

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have made a Timer application in android containing four activities.Now i when i install .apk in my android device it displays all four activity icons on screens rather than showing only main-activity icon..please help me..my manifest file is as below;

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.timerdemo2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NewProject"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Timedetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_timedetails"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_project"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead of above &
 Remember main activity of Application add  tag

```
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    
            </intent-filter>
```

Your manifest Should be like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.timerdemo2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NewProject"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
             android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Timedetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_timedetails"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_project"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It because you are applying `</intent-filter>` to all activities instead to main, just make changes like below

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.timerdemo2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".NewProject"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_new_project"
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".Timedetails"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_timedetails"
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ListActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

[There is quite a bit of documentation on intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: Tnx very much robin...!hey do you know how can one kill process by using "back" button of AVD .Thanx in advance,,,:)

Comment: Override onpause method and finish your process.

Comment: Can i show u my code bro?that u can better understand my problem..?if u dnt mind?

Comment: your this issue is solve? if yes then ask another question, else join android chat room.

Comment: ok...!i've asked another 1 but no one has answered it..so..:O...!its k ...tnx 1ce again bro

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108210/ive-made-1-application-in-android-of-timer-timer-in-three-edittexts-but-its-not#comment19521751_14108210

Comment: @RobinHood- get it? the Link?

Comment: @RobinHood---ohk..sorry...take ur time..sir..!

Answer (score 0):

Change your Intent Filters ,  the MAIN/LAUNCHER intent filter essentially tells android that the activity is the app's starting activity
instead of using :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Use :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```